# Decreasing the resistance in the input circuit of a transistor and its effect on the output current and voltage

Tags: current, voltage

**With reference to this circuit:**
[image]

**Question:** When the resistance \$R\$ is decreased, how does the lamp's brightness and the voltmeter's reading change?

**My answer:** The input resistance of a transistor circuit is given as \$r = (\frac{\Delta V_{BE}}{\Delta I_{B}})\$. So when R decreases, \$r\$ decreases, and hence \$\Delta I_B\$ increases (as they are inversely proportional from the equation). From the output characteristics, an increase in \$I_B\$ leads to an increase in \$I_C\$ and therefore the current in the lamp increases; leading to it getting brighter. As \$I_C\$ gets higher, voltage in the output circuit increases and the voltmeter has a higher reading as compared to its initial value.

**Answer given:** 
[image]

Even though my notion that the brightness and the voltmeter increases is right, my reasoning is quite wrong. How does the circuit become "more forward biased" when \$R\$ is decreased? And why is it that \$I_B\$ decreases while \$I_C\$ increases. Why aren't both of them increasing? And if possible, could you say why my concepts are wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will divide the answer into two parts:

1) (`r=(ΔVBEΔIB)`) is the formula for dynamic resistance when the input is A.C. Here you should apply the KVL. (`Vbb – IB Rb = 0.7`). Thus, decreasing the value of R will increase (`Ib`). And **if** the transistor is in active region, `Ic` will be proportional to `Ib` and hence the bulb will glow brighter.

2) If you keep on decreasing the value of R, transistor will enter into saturation. I am guessing the book means to say **saturation** by using the term **more forward biased**. Because in saturation, (`VCE`) = 0.2V.

Comment: I wrote the subscripts notation in word and copied here. Please help me edit properly.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.

Comment: Then is the answer given wrong? For it states that IB decreases and IC increases. IB must increase, right?                    And how could I increase/decrease the value of Vbe from 0.7? Will it change when I add an AC voltage in the input circuit?

Comment: yes, the "answer given" is wrong.  The "answer given" should have the words "decreasing the base current" replaced with "increasing base current".

Comment: Yes, as @Marla said, the answer is wrong. Also, in saturation Ib is more than (b)Ic [beta*Ic].
You can change Vb (voltage that you measure between the base terminal and ground) but not Vbe (voltage between base terminal and the emitter). It will always be 0.7.

Comment: @IndoUbt: If I have answered your question, you can tick mark it as answered.

Comment: @explorer Oh yes, forgot to do that! Thanks again :) [btw can't upvote due to low rep]